# grails plugin dependencies with classifiers

Tags: grails

In Grails 1.3.7, I'm trying to declare a dependency on a plugin with a classifier. I've tried the following:

```
plugins {
    compile group: 'org.foo', name: 'myplugin', version: '0.8', classifier: 'grails1'     
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I redeploy the plugin (to a local Artifactory) without a classifier in the version and remove the classifier from the dependency declaration, it works.

Comment: Just for curiosity, did `compile 'org.foo:myplugin:0.8:grails1'` works?

Comment: @SérgioMichels no, that syntax is invalid. AFAIK the classifier is part of the version, so I think the syntax should be `compile 'org.foo:myplugin:0.8-grails1` but it doesn't work either

Comment: Looking at the code for `IvyDependencyManager`, the form you've tried with `classifier:'..'` is supposed to work for `m2compatible` resolvers.  How exactly have you defined your local artifactory repository in BuildConfig?