# Grails adding dependency with "classifier" does not work

Tags: grails

First i want to inform that same kind of question was asked here 
  [grails plugin dependencies with classifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939189/grails-plugin-dependencies-with-classifiers) but they is no answer .

I am trying to add jar  "json-lib.jar" and its dependency to BuildConfig.groovy file . This dependency has element called  because of this i cannot able to download the dependency .

```
 dependencies {runtime group:'net.sf.json-lib', name:'json-lib',  classifier:'jdk15',version:'2.4'}
```

But this does not help .

I also tried like this

`dependencies { runtime 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15'}

This one also doesn't help

Even tried creating a maven pom-file and added "json-lib.jar" dependency to pom file but getting the same but if try using same dependency in my java maven project it works fine

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
<artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But this one also doesn't  helped.

My error message on trying to Refresh dependency(In STS)

```
WARNINGS
    [FAILED     ] net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar:  (0ms)


==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\Software\Groovy -STS\Installed Directory\grails-2.1.1/plugins/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-json-lib/tags/RELEASE_2.4/grails-json-lib-2.4.jar

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== localMavenResolver: tried

  C:\Users\Target/.m2/repository/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== ebrRelease: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== ebrExternal: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried

  http://download.java.net/maven/2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== localMavenResolver: tried

  C:\Users\Target/.m2/repository/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


     :: problems summary ::
     :::: WARNINGS
    [FAILED     ] net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar:  (0ms)


==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\Software\Groovy -STS\Installed Directory\grails-2.1.1/lib/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/jars/json-lib-2.4.jar

  C:\Users\Target\Software\Groovy -STS\Installed Directory\grails-2.1.1/lib/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/bundles/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\Software\Groovy -STS\Installed Directory\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\Software\Groovy -STS\Installed Directory\grails-2.1.1\dist/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\Target\Software\Groovy -STS\Installed Directory\grails-2.1.1/plugins/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-json-lib/tags/RELEASE_2.4/grails-json-lib-2.4.jar

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== localMavenResolver: tried

  C:\Users\Target/.m2/repository/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== ebrRelease: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== ebrExternal: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried

  http://download.java.net/maven/2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

==== localMavenResolver: tried

  C:\Users\Target/.m2/repository/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, see here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4#gradle

```
dependencies {
  runtime 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4'
}
```

Also, check if your have the MavenLocal and MavenCentral repos enabled:

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
    // from public Maven repositories

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
```